# How to find who deleted a view from DB with SIMPLE recovery model

Tags: sql, sql-server

We found out this morning that one view is missed in customer's production DB. It was not problem to restore it from testing copy, but my boss wants to know how it happend to avoid such situations in future.

I found some scenarios for `fn_dblog` but wasnt able to find which Operation type I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture drop view events from the default trace, assuming they happened recently:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
   LoginName,
   HostName,
   StartTime,
   ObjectName
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 47
AND ObjectName = N'MyView';
```

(As an aside, this method doesn't have any dependencies on recovery model; however you should be aware that content in the default trace will roll out eventually, so you are unlikely to find out who dropped an object 6 months ago. How long it stays around depends on a lot of variables for each instance.)

Comment: Could you explain why the path is not using in the default format SELECT @path = [path] FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1, please.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko because you want to start from the first file in the sequence, log.trc, not the current file. This ensures you capture all of the activity generated...